# Obtaining a pandas series by constructing its name as a string

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm looking to construct a series name as a string and get its values for a given index, or set its value for a particular index. For example:

```
def getEntityValue(self, testCase, ent_order):
    if ent_order == 1:
        return self.testInputEnt1[testCase]
    elif ent_order == 2:
        return self.testInputEnt2[testCase]
    elif ent_order == 3:
        return self.testInputEnt3[testCase]
```

Or another one:

```
def setEntityValue(self, testCase, ent_order, value):
    if ent_order == 1:
        self.testResultEnt1[testCase] = value
    elif ent_order == 2:
        self.testResultEnt2[testCase] = value
    elif ent_order == 3:
        self.testResultEnt3[testCase] = value
```

Is there a simpler way of constructing this testInputEntX series in a better way? I'm well aware of the fact that it's ideal to use other type of data structures where the values 1, 2, 3 can be used as another index and testInputEnt can be a list of series. But I will have to stick to these series for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be refactored like:

```
def getEntityValue(self, testCase, ent_order):
    return getattr(self, f'testInputEnt{ent_order}')[testCase]
    #getattr(self, f'testInputEnt{ent_order}')[testCase] = value
```

But, why don't you use a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) instead of N pandas series? You can use [`DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) to get and update a cell

```
def getEntityValue(self, testCase, ent_order):
    return self.testResultEnt.at[ent_order, testCase]
    #self.testResultEnt.at[ent_order, testCase] = value
```

Comment: That works. Thanks! Unfortunately, I'm limited to use such Series for this project and cannot make a change in the data structure.